# lftp rolls back the transfer process

Tags: lftp

i am trying to transfer a 2GB file using lftp, the connection is successful, the tranfer starts, but when it reaches 15% (sometime a bit more, sometime a bit less) it starts all over again, it rolls back to 0% and restarts the process, any idea what it could be? my command:

```
lftp -ssl-allow -u 'user,pass' -e "set ftp:ssl-allow true; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ftp:ssl-auth TLS; set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-protect-list true;cd DIR;mput FILENAME;exit" ftps.COMPLETE_HOST
```

Comment: Why do you think the fault lies with lftp and not the remote server / intervening infrastructure?

Comment: lack of experience, i do this rarely

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the server does not support REST command so it cannot restart incomplete transfers and lftp starts from the beginning.

Why the transfer breaks is another question. Instabilities in the network may cause it.